# What is the time complexity of __gcd?

Tags: c++, std

What is the time complexity of __gcd(m,n) function? Also, does it use the Euclidean method to calculate gcd?

e.g. code

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std; 

int main() { 
    cout << "gcd(10, 25) : " << __gcd(6, 20) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: It's non-standard, so you have to check your compiler documentation for that.

Comment: What compiler are you using? `__gcd` is not in the standard library. [`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) is in the [`<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric) header starting from C++17 though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it use Euclidean method to calculate gcd of two values. It's complexity is (2)  algorithm, where n is the upper limit of *a* and *b*.

Details : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-time-complexity-of-Euclids-GCD-algorithm

Answer (score -4):

Yes, its using the euclidian ([Implementation of the in-built __gcd method in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981380/implementation-of-the-in-built-gcd-method-in-c))

And the time complexity is O(n) ([Time complexity of Euclid's Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980416/time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm))

Comment: you probably refer to the top answer on that question. I have to admit, I dont understand it completely, it seems to argue with the number of digits and denotes `N` as the number of digits. However, note that the number of digits of a number does not scale linear